# Unable to scrape data from a particular webpage using Watir

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

I've used Watir to successfully web scrape before, but I'm having trouble web scraping this particular web page.

https://kroger.softcoin.com/programs/kroger/digital_coupons/?banner=Smiths&origin=DigitalCoupons

When I visit the page on a regular browser, I can see the page reload itself two or three times every time and I'm thinking that's where the problem comes from.  I've tried using

```
Watir::Wait.until { @browser.div(id: "offer-105653").visible? }
```

but that doesn't work.  I've successfully used the code above on other webpages as a test, but it doesn't seem to work for the Kroger website. I am not sure how to fix.

```
def save
    require 'watir'
    require 'phantomjs'

    @browser = Watir::Browser.new:phantomjs
    @browser.goto "https://kroger.softcoin.com/programs/kroger/digital_coupons/?banner=Smiths&origin=DigitalCoupons"
    @browser.li(id: "1768173").wait_until(&:present?).text
    @products = @browser.divs
    @products.each do |x|
        Smith.create(title: x.text) 
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

`#visible?` makes the assumption that the element first exists. If it does not exist in the DOM yet it will immediately raise an exception rather than continuing to wait, so it is usually not what you want to use when polling for an element.

Try:

```
@browser.div(id: "offer-105653").wait_until(&:present?).text`
```

Comment: Hmm.  That did not work.  I also edited my post to include my save method. And this was the error raised "timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for true condition on #<Watir::LI: located: false; {:id=>"1768173", :tag_name=>"li"}>"

Comment: That error means that the defined element is not in the DOM after 30 seconds of looking for it? Are you sure the page is loading? I can get it working in Chrome. Also, Chrome is faster than phantomjs and if you really do need headless, you can do: `Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true`

Comment: Do you know if ChromeDriver can be used with c9.io?  And if so, where would I place ChromeDriver on the path if I'm using a Chromebook?  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Use webdrivers gem and make sure you have permission for ~/.webdrivers

Comment: Installed the 'webdrivers' gem, but getting the error "unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498513 (2c63aa53b2c658de596ed550eb5267ec5967b351),platform=Linux 4.9.17-c9 x86_64)"
I'm looking into solutions on how to fix this, but if you have an idea off the top of your head on how to fix it as well...

Comment: Yeah, that means the browser isn't installed on the system. :-)

Comment: When you say not installed on the system do you mean on the laptop I'm using or in my IDE?  Because I'm using a ChromeBook and Chrome by default comes with it.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. How are you running ruby code on a chromebook?

Comment: Haha I've been using c9.io    An IDE in the cloud.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't... Whatever, chromedriver doesn't work on chromebook. :-)

Comment: I'm curious, doesn't what?

Comment: Chromedriver does not drive chrome on a chromebook. Why not is a question for Google.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially what is happening is that behind the scenes webdriver or watir are trying to use CSS selectors to select that element.

The thing is, ID values starting with a number were disallowed under HTML4, but are now allowed in HTML5.  However, despite being allowed in HTML5, CSS Selection does not allow selecting by IDs starting with a number unless you get tricky.  For that to work you have to escape the first character.

You can see this in the developer console if you navigate to that page and issue a command such as `$$("#\\31 755189")` it will find the element just fine. But if you try `$$("#1768173")` you will see an invalid selector error.  (Note those examples are likely to be valid only for a short period, as that is a dynamic page subject to change

I would recommend trying the following in your code and see if that gets it working.

```
@browser.li(id: "\\31 768173").wait_until(&:present?).text
```

If that does work, then to allow it to work without escaping the first numeral the watir devs may have to add special case logic to selecting by ID to escape the first character when it is a numeral